# How can I pass a variable from one razor page to another?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am making a web app using razor pages and I need to pass a string variable that's in my signup.cshtml to signin.cshtml. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a string variable from signup.cshtml to signin.cshtml.cs.Here is a demo:

signup.cshtml:

```
<form asp-page="signin" asp-page-handler="Test" method="post">
    <input name="TestString" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

signin.cshtml.cs:

```
public void OnPostTest(string TestString)
{
}
```

result:
[image]

If you want to pass a string variable from signup.cshtml handler to signin.cshtml handler.Here is a demo:

signup.cshtml.cs:

```
 public IActionResult OnGet()
 {
     var TestString= "test";
     return RedirectToPage("signin","Test", new { TestString = TestString });
 }
```

signin.cshtml.cs:

```
public void OnGetTest(string TestString)
{
}
```

result:
[image]